# redirect to subversion project after authorization

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, httpd.conf, redirection

I am trying to figure out how to have apache redirect to a subversion repository after the requested URL is authorized for a user. After trying a lot of combinations the best result I can get is ave apache to redirect to target SVN repo folder as a web directory rather than the folder as a subversion repository.

The authorization steps work as expected, approving or denying the user, but then the redirect fails with  Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/svn/svnRepo1/,

Folder set up
/home/svn/svnRepo1   << the repo is working via myurl.com/svnRepo1 as expected
/home/userA/myurl.com/protected

NB: the myurl.com/protected/svnRepo1 web folder does not exist

in the url conf files I have

svn.conf

```
    <Location /svn>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /home/svn
    </Location>
```

in the url.conf I have

```
 <Location /protected/svnRepo1>
            AuthType openid-connect
            #Require valid-user
            Require claim folders:svnRepo1
  </Location> 
  Alias /protected/svnRepo1 /home/svn/svnRepo1
```

Lastly I would like to make the directives so a user can NOT access the repo directly by 
myurl.com/svnRepo1 as this would bypass the authorization process.

Thx
Art

Comment: Is there some good reason why you can't just put the auth directives directly onto /svn?  Why the redirect?

Comment: yes, i need different urls for each svn project (myurl.com/project-x/svnName) and each project has different authorization providers, so I can not see a way to set this up on a per project basis. Can you provide some code examples to do it directly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this would be a more direct approach:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /home/svn
</Location>

<Location /svn/svnRepo1>
  AuthType openid-connect
  Require claim folders:svnRepo1
</Location>
```

avoiding the need for the `Alias` directive.

But anyway, as for your problem error message `Directory index forbidden by Options directive`, all you should need to fix that is to add `Options +Indexes` within one or more of the `<Location>` directives.

Comment: @Schulman, unfortunately that did not work, I need the alias as there are several sub domains pointing to the svn directory that contains sub projects. Your code did not trigger the openid auth request.

Comment: OK.  Well ignoring my suggestion about the Alias, did `Options +Indexes` solve your error message?